# java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out but able to open in my browser

Tags: java, java-io

I am able to open the webpage from my machine. But I am getting below error when I am trying to read the web page as shown below.

My java Code is follows.

```
public class SearchPage {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        try {
            // Create a URL for the desired page
            URL u = new URL("http://www.google.com");

           // Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("123.0.0.1", 8080));

            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String str;
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {

                System.out.println("Web page "+str);
            }
                in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally{

        }
    }
```

}

I am getting below error when I run the code.

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:395)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$4.run(HttpClient.java:458)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.privilegedOpenServer(HttpClient.java:440)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:521)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:234)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:307)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:324)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:970)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:949)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:836)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1172)
    at nag.search.web.SearchPage.main(SearchPage.java:26)
```

Comment: When I run the code from my machine it works. Do you have some anti virus or firewall blocking your ide from making outbound connections?

Comment: Oh great hear that it works on your machine. I have to find out, may be you are right.

Comment: I suggest that your browser has an HTTP or SOCKS proxy configured. Your code doesn't

Comment: No proxy configured, because I am testing from my work place, it seems they restricted some access, but is working outside my office network. thanks

Comment: If you're testing from your workplace they almost certainly have a web proxy configured. The fact that it works outside just about proves it.